# Deployment Angular7 project to Heroku issue

Tags: heroku, angular7, angular-universal

I have project I've create by using Angular Universal
Now I want't to deploy it to heroku but I got some difficulties with package.json

After use
`git push heroku master`

I'm getting the next error:
`A module may be missing from 'dependencies' in package.json`

There is no description about which module is missing

Here is my `package.json` file: 
`{
  "name": "street-z",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "engines": {
    "node": "10.15.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "compile:server": "webpack --config webpack.server.config.js --progress --colors",
    "serve:ssr": "node dist/server",
    "build:ssr": "npm run build:client-and-server-bundles && npm run compile:server",
    "build:client-and-server-bundles": "ng build --prod && ng run StreetZ:server:production",
    "start:ssr": "npm run build:ssr & npm run serve:ssr",
    "start:heroku": "node dist/server",
    "postinstall": "npm run build:ssr"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^8.2.7",
    "@angular/cdk": "^8.2.1",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.7",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.7",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.7",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.7",
    "@angular/http": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.7",
    "@angular/platform-server": "~8.2.7",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.7",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^5.1.1",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^8.3.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "^8.3.0",
    "@nguniversal/express-engine": "^7.1.1",
    "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "0.0.0",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.37.7",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "^0.9.0",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "core-js": "^3.2.1",
    "express": "^4.15.2",
    "firebase": "^7.2.0",
    "ngx-device-detector": "^1.3.11",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.3",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.803.8",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.3.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.7",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.7",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.4.2",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~12.7.11",
    "bufferutil": "^4.0.1",
    "codelyzer": "~5.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.4.1",
    "tslint": "~5.20.0",
    "typescript": "^3.5.3",
    "utf-8-validate": "^5.0.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0",
    "ws": "^7.1.2",
    "xhr2": "^0.2.0"
  }
}`

I've tried to pass all the 'devDependencies' to 'dependencies' 
and use `heroku config:set NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false`

None of them helped me

tnx for your help

Comment: did you run `npm install` in the directory after you changed `dependencies`?

Comment: yep - did it couple of times.
it's run fine on localhost.

Comment: this error appears to me only when I'm trying to deploy to heroku